# How can I add summary rows to a pandas DataFrame calculated on multiple columns by agg functions like mean, median, etc

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have some data with multiple observations for a given Collector, Date, Sample, and Type where the observation values vary by ID.

```
import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = """Collector,Date,Sample,Type,ID,Value
Emily,2014-06-20,201,HV,A,34
Emily,2014-06-20,201,HV,B,22
Emily,2014-06-20,201,HV,C,10
Emily,2014-06-20,201,HV,D,5
John,2014-06-22,221,HV,A,40
John,2014-06-22,221,HV,B,39
John,2014-06-22,221,HV,C,11
John,2014-06-22,221,HV,D,2
Emily,2014-06-23,203,HV,A,33
Emily,2014-06-23,203,HV,B,35
Emily,2014-06-23,203,HV,C,13
Emily,2014-06-23,203,HV,D,1
John,2014-07-01,218,HV,A,35
John,2014-07-01,218,HV,B,29
John,2014-07-01,218,HV,C,13
John,2014-07-01,218,HV,D,1
"""

>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(data), parse_dates="Date")
```

After doing some graphing with the data in this long format, I pivot it to a wide summary table format with columns for each ID.

```
>>> table = df.pivot_table(index=["Collector", "Date", "Sample", "Type"], columns="ID", values="Value")

ID                                 A   B   C  D
Collector Date       Sample Type               
Emily     2014-06-20 201    HV    34  22  10  5
          2014-06-23 203    HV    33  35  13  1
John      2014-06-22 221    HV    40  39  11  2
          2014-07-01 218    HV    35  29  13  1
```

However, I can't find a concise way to calculate and add some summary rows to the wide format data with mean, median, and maybe some custom aggregation function applied to each of the ID-based columns. This is what I want to end up with:

```
ID Collector        Date  Sample Type   A    B    C   D
0      Emily  2014-06-20     201   HV  34   22   10   5
2       John  2014-06-22     221   HV  40   39   11   2
1      Emily  2014-06-23     203   HV  33   35   13   1
3       John  2014-07-01     218   HV  35   29   13   1
4       mean                          35.5 31.3 11.8 2.3
5     median                          34.5 32.0 12.0 1.5
```

I tried things like calling `mean` or `median` on the summary table, but I end up with a Series rather than a row I can concatenate to the summary table. The summary rows I want are sort of like pivot_table margins, but the aggregation function is not `sum`.

```
>>> table.mean()
ID
A     35.50
B     31.25
C     11.75
D      2.25
dtype: float64

>>> table.median()
ID
A     34.5
B     32.0
C     12.0
D      1.5
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `aggfunc=[np.mean, np.median]` to compute both the means and the medians. Then you could use `margins=True` to also obtain the means and medians for each column and for each row.

```
result = df.pivot_table(index=["Collector", "Date", "Sample", "Type"], 
    columns="ID", values="Value", margins=True, 
    aggfunc=[np.mean, np.median]).stack(level=0)
```

yields

```
ID                                          A      B      C     D      All
Collector Date       Sample Type                                          
Emily     2014-06-20 201    HV   mean    34.0  22.00  10.00  5.00  17.7500
                                 median  34.0  22.00  10.00  5.00  16.0000
          2014-06-23 203    HV   mean    33.0  35.00  13.00  1.00  20.5000
                                 median  33.0  35.00  13.00  1.00  23.0000
John      2014-06-22 221    HV   mean    40.0  39.00  11.00  2.00  23.0000
                                 median  40.0  39.00  11.00  2.00  25.0000
          2014-07-01 218    HV   mean    35.0  29.00  13.00  1.00  19.5000
                                 median  35.0  29.00  13.00  1.00  21.0000
All                              mean    35.5  31.25  11.75  2.25  20.1875
                                 median  34.5  32.00  12.00  1.50  17.5000
```

---

Yes, `result` contains more data than you asked for, but

```
result.loc['All']
```

has the additional values:

```
ID                          A      B      C     D      All
Date Sample Type                                          
                 mean    35.5  31.25  11.75  2.25  20.1875
                 median  34.5  32.00  12.00  1.50  17.5000
```

---

Or, you could further subselect `result` to get just the rows you are looking for:

```
result.index.names = [u'Collector', u'Date', u'Sample', u'Type', u'aggfunc']
mask = result.index.get_level_values('aggfunc') == 'mean'
mask[-1] = True
result = result.loc[mask]
print(result)
```

yields

```
ID                                           A      B      C     D      All
Collector Date       Sample Type aggfunc                                   
Emily     2014-06-20 201    HV   mean     34.0  22.00  10.00  5.00  17.7500
          2014-06-23 203    HV   mean     33.0  35.00  13.00  1.00  20.5000
John      2014-06-22 221    HV   mean     40.0  39.00  11.00  2.00  23.0000
          2014-07-01 218    HV   mean     35.0  29.00  13.00  1.00  19.5000
All                              mean     35.5  31.25  11.75  2.25  20.1875
                                 median   34.5  32.00  12.00  1.50  17.5000
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be super clean, but you could assign to the new entries with `.loc`.

```
In [131]: table_mean = table.mean()

In [132]: table_median = table.median()

In [134]: table.loc['Mean', :] = table_mean.values

In [135]: table.loc['Median', :] = table_median.values

In [136]: table
Out[136]: 
ID                                   A      B      C     D
Collector Date       Sample Type                          
Emily     2014-06-20 201    HV    34.0  22.00  10.00  5.00
          2014-06-23 203    HV    33.0  35.00  13.00  1.00
John      2014-06-22 221    HV    40.0  39.00  11.00  2.00
          2014-07-01 218    HV    35.0  29.00  13.00  1.00
Mean                              35.5  31.25  11.75  2.25
Median                            34.5  32.00  12.00  1.50
```