# Sum all value columns and add total row in df based on groups

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that looks like the below.

```
tmp = [('A','a', 1,1,0), ('A','b', 2,1,0), ('A','c', 3,2,1), ('B','a', 1,2,3), ('B','b', 0,1,2)]
df = pd.DataFrame(tmp, columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3'])
```

**Out:**

```
    Col1    Col2    Val1    Val2    Val3
0   A   a   1   1   0
1   A   b   2   1   0
2   A   c   3   2   1
3   B   a   1   2   3
4   B   b   0   1   2
```

I'd like to sum the values in val1,val2, and val3 based on col1 grouping. I can get one column to format correctly using the below.

```
tmp = tmp.groupby(['Col1','Col2'])['Val1'].sum().unstack()
tmp = tmp.assign(Total=tmp.sum(1)).stack().to_frame('Val1')
```

**Out:**

```
    Val1
Col1    Col2    
A   a   1.00
    b   2.00
    c   3.00
Total   6.00
B   a   1.00
    b   0.00
Total   1.00
```

My goal is to have Val2 and Val3 columns added in the above df but I have been unable to find a clean way to chain the above method together. Any help greatly appreciated.

**Expected output:**

```
              Val1  Val2  Val3 
Col1    Col2    
A         a   1.00  1.00  0.00
          b   2.00  1.00  0.00
          c   3.00  2.00  1.00
Total         6.00  4.00  1.00
B         a   1.00  2.00  3.00
          b   0.00  1.00  2.00
Total         1.00  3.00  5.00
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26025607/how-can-i-add-summary-rows-to-a-pandas-dataframe-calculated-on-multiple-columns\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Method 1:

You can use the `pivot_table` method which is linked in the comments by BEN_YO, in this case we have to use `GroupBy.apply` since we want to apply it to each group seperately:

```
df.groupby('Col1').apply(
    lambda x: x.pivot_table(
        index=['Col1', 'Col2'], 
        aggfunc='sum', 
        margins=True,
        margins_name='Total')
)

                 Val1  Val2  Val3
Col1 Col1  Col2                  
A    A     a        1     1     0
           b        2     1     0
           c        3     2     1
     Total          6     4     1
B    B     a        1     2     3
           b        0     1     2
     Total          1     3     5
```

---

#### Method 2:

We can loop over our groups and use `.loc` to add our totals:

```
grps = df.groupby(['Col1'])
dfs = []
for _, grp in grps:
    grp = grp.set_index(['Col1', 'Col2'])
    grp.loc[('', 'Total'), :] = grp.sum()
    dfs.append(grp)

pd.concat(dfs)

            Val1  Val2  Val3
Col1 Col2                   
A    a       1.0   1.0   0.0
     b       2.0   1.0   0.0
     c       3.0   2.0   1.0
     Total   6.0   4.0   1.0
B    a       1.0   2.0   3.0
     b       0.0   1.0   2.0
     Total   1.0   3.0   5.0
```